# What is the point of the `Function` identifier on `window`?

Tags: javascript

If you open your console and type `Function`, it auto completes it for you, indicating that the indentifier `Function` is part of the winddow object. It appears as though the `Function` identifier refers to an empty anonymous function.

[image]

What is the point of the `Function` identifier on `window`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`Function`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) is a global variable. Global variables are properties of the global object. In browsers, the global object is `window`.

If you are asking what the purpose of `Function` itself is: It's a constructor function (just like `Object`, `Array` or `RegExp`) to create new function objects. It lets you create a new function from code contained in a string (almost like `eval`). E.g.:

```
var myFunc = new Function('return 42;');
console.log(myFunc()); // 42
```

Functions created this way behave like they had been declared in global scope, i.e. they do not close over the scope they actually have been created in.

This can be useful for browser tools which evaluate user provided JS code provided, like the [Babel REPL](http://babeljs.io/repl/).